# TikZ node parameter and pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys, tikz-node

I am trying to pass some parameters to a node style and found an answer for simple cases: [Is it possible to consider a single optional parameter among three in node declaration?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254865/is-it-possible-to-consider-a-single-optional-parameter-among-three-in-node-decla)

However, I cannot implement it as part of a more complex structure. These arguments are stored into `pgfkeys` and must be passed in a command named `\ColorEdges` before being sent to the nodes (this particular key being used several times somewhere else).

In the MWE below, it partially works: I can print node labels saying "blue" for "Tom" and "red" for "Jane". The same mechanism does not work to choose the `draw` color (uncomment the line `draw=\expandafter\ColorEdges\expandafter{\peoplecolor},` to see the problem).

Does someone understand why?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    
    % Define several keys for each person
    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        persdata/.is choice,
        persdata/TomID/.style={
            name            = {Tom Surname},
            people color    = {Tom}
        }
    }

    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        persdata/.is choice,
        persdata/JaneID/.style={
            name            = {Jane Anothersurname},
            people color    = {Jane}
        }
    }

    % Define new keys in database
    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        name/.store in=\usualname,
        people color/.store in=\peoplecolor
    }

    % Associate color based on people color
    \newcommand{\ColorEdges}[1]{
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Tom}{blue}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{Jane}{red}{%
        }}
    }

    % Define command to print people data
    \newcommand\PrintPeople[1]{
        
        % Locate appropriate keys set     
        \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,persdata=#1}%
        
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                peoplebox/.style={
                    very thick,
                    fill=blue!40}
                ]
                
                \node [peoplebox,
%               draw=\expandafter\ColorEdges\expandafter{\peoplecolor},
                label=\expandafter\ColorEdges\expandafter{\peoplecolor}] {
                    \ifdefined\usualname
                    \usualname
                    \fi
                };      
                
            \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \PrintPeople{TomID}
    
    \PrintPeople{JaneID}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: very good question! very very very good question!

Comment: @AlMA you should post your question [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your conditional, `\ifstrequal` is *not* expandable.  It works in the `label` command because that typesets the result, and so is processed in TeX's "stomach".  It doesn't work in the `draw` command because that tries to expand the result and use it in other commands, and so fails on the non-expandable tokens.

You can see this by putting in the following:

```
\edef\exptest{\ColorEdges{Tom}}
\show\exptest
```

So there isn't a way to tweak your code in a small way to make it work.  There are a variety of ways that your code could be made workable, and the right one depends a little bit on what you are trying to achieve with this.

I think that the simplest would be to define colour aliases.  You have to, at some point, decide that `Tom` is `red` and `Jane` is `blue`, so why not simply alias the colours?  All it needs is:

```
\colorlet{Tom}{red}
\colorlet{Jane}{blue}
```

This has an advantage over your code in that it is very easy to maintain and to add extra names/colours to the list (with your nested conditionals you are going to end up with a sea of braces).  It keeps all the colour definitions in one place (which is why I presume that you haven't put them in the data) and makes it very easy to use - simply use the alias anywhere you would put a colour.

If you did want a conditional in a similar fashion to what you have, then you could use LaTeX3 code here.  That provides an expandable string comparison.  This also has the bonus that it can expand its arguments on request, so you can define:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\ColorEdges}[1]{
  \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1}{Tom}{blue}
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1}{Jane}{red}
    {
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

with this then `draw=\ColorEdges{\peoplecolor}` works as-is.

If you wanted to control the expansion yourself (at the invocation stage) then a neat trick with pgfkeys is to define a wrapper key that does the actual colour setting and then use the `.expand once` handler on that.

So with `\ColorEdges` defined as:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\ColorEdges}[1]{
  \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{Tom}{blue}
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{Jane}{red}
    {
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

so that it *doesn't* automatically expand its arguments then you define:

```
\tikzset{
  set draw color/.style={
    draw=\ColorEdges{#1}
  }
}
```

and invoke it via:

```
set draw color/.expand once=\peoplecolor
```

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer. I will have a lot of testing to do :) I will see which one is the best solution.

Comment: The second option works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I found a *terribly **ugly*** solution. The only thing to say in its favor is that it works.

I redefined the command `\ColorEdges` to print `\node []` including the parameters I want to adjust. Then I call it and follow it with `{my node content}`. Note that a `peoplebox` type of node can still be defined inside the `tikzpicture` environment and be taken into account when used through the `\ColorEdges` command.

The MWE is below but I will welcome any answer cleaner than this one :)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    
    % Define several keys for each person
    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        persdata/.is choice,
        persdata/TomID/.style={
            name            = {Tom Surname},
            people color    = {Tom}
        }
    }

    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        persdata/.is choice,
        persdata/JaneID/.style={
            name            = {Jane Anothersurname},
            people color    = {Jane}
        }
    }

    % Define new keys in database
    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        name/.store in=\usualname,
        people color/.store in=\peoplecolor
    }

    % Associate color based on people color
    \newcommand{\ColorEdges}[1]{
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Tom}{\node [peoplebox, draw=blue]}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{Jane}{\node [peoplebox, draw=red]}{%
        }}
    }

    % Define command to print people complete data in English
    \newcommand\PrintPeople[1]{
        
        % Locate appropriate keys set     
        \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,persdata=#1}%
        
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                peoplebox/.style={
                    very thick,
                    fill=blue!20}
                ]
                
                \expandafter\ColorEdges\expandafter{\peoplecolor}{
                    \ifdefined\usualname
                    \usualname
                    \fi
                };
                
            \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \PrintPeople{TomID}
    
    \PrintPeople{JaneID}
    
\end{document}
```